# Which site is appropriate for extreme temperature vs sound velocity?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My old college notes (c. 1980's) list a table ranging only from -40 deg C to 200 deg C. (lower temp less velocity). I wish to extend this table from (say) absolute zero to millions of degrees, but have no formulas available. Non-SE browsing yielded no results.

Comment: Most likely [the physics site](http://physics.stackexchange.com) however I am not sure if it would be well received, as the first result for ["speed of sound in air"](https://www.google.com/search?q=speed%20of%20sound%20in%20air) is [this calculator](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-speedsound.htm) which you can use to calculate for any temperature you want, and [the Wikipedia article on speed of sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound#Speed_of_sound_in_ideal_gases_and_air) which contains all of the equations for calculating speed of sound at any temperature in any phase.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a question for [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com).

There is a caveat - the medium through which the sound moves. The table in your notes probably is about sound moving through air as we know it. For the extreme values you are interested in, you cannot assume that air will have the gaseous state in which we know it, or that we can speak of "air" at all.

Considering the nature of air under extreme temperatures would be a good first research step, before posting your question there. It would give you an upper and lower limit for your extended table.